# Binding does not live long enough when storing a reference to a vector item in a hash map

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm new at Rust and still struggling with the borrow checker and getting lifetimes right.

Here's a simple struct I've started to build - it stores collections of command-line argument like things (which can be represented by a `--string` or a `-c` or both):

```
struct OptionMap<'a, T: 'a> {
    name: HashMap<String, &'a T>,
    short_name: HashMap<char, &'a T>,
    options: Vec<T>
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> OptionMap<'a, T> {
    pub fn new() -> OptionMap<'a, T> {
        OptionMap {
            name: HashMap::new(),
            short_name: HashMap::new(),
            options: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn register(&mut self, name: &OptionName, option: T) {        
        if name.name.is_some() {
            self.name.insert(name.name.unwrap().to_owned(), &option);
        }

        if name.short_name.is_some() {
            self.short_name.insert(name.short_name.unwrap(), &option);
        }

        self.options.push(option);
    }
}
```

I get two of these errors (one for each of the `&option` parameters I wrote):

```
   Compiling glam v0.1.0 (file:///Users/carson/Projects/glam)
src/options.rs:57:66: 57:72 error: `option` does not live long enough
src/options.rs:57                 self.name.insert(name.name.unwrap().to_owned(), &option);
                                                                                   ^~~~~~
src/options.rs:54:62: 66:6 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 54:61...
src/options.rs:54     pub fn register(&mut self, name: &OptionName, option: T) {
src/options.rs:55         {
src/options.rs:56             if name.name.is_some() {
src/options.rs:57                 self.name.insert(name.name.unwrap().to_owned(), &option);
src/options.rs:58             }
src/options.rs:59         }
                  ...
src/options.rs:54:62: 66:6 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the scope of parameters for function at 54:61
src/options.rs:54     pub fn register(&mut self, name: &OptionName, option: T) {
src/options.rs:55         {
src/options.rs:56             if name.name.is_some() {
src/options.rs:57                 self.name.insert(name.name.unwrap().to_owned(), &option);
src/options.rs:58             }
src/options.rs:59         }
                  ...
```

I pass a reference to each of the hash maps (so they borrow it) and then pass the option straight to the vector to move it there, so that the option doesn't go out of scope.

It seems like the scope of `'a` and the scope of `option` should be the same to me - since `OptionMap` is created with lifetime `'a`, and `T` is bound by that lifetime as well, and `option` gets moved into `options` at the end of the function. What am I missing? I feel like I'm constantly fighting with lifetimes in Rust, like there's something that hasn't clicked for me yet.

Comment: I *would* like to say that I'm aware of `docopt` et al. in rust, but writing it myself is a good exercise in getting comfortable with the language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I pass a reference to each of the hash maps (so they borrow it) and
>   then pass the option straight to the vector to move it there, so that
>   the option doesn't go out of scope.

Once something is borrowed, you can't move it elsewhere.

If you place an element into a vector and borrow it from there, you can't mutate the vector until the borrow ends.

In other words your current approach won't work.

The simplest solution is probably to store indices into the vector in your hash maps.

Alternatively, it might be possible to design a fancy key that can be compared to both the short and long names, and then you can store the option directly in a single hash map. I say "might" because I'm not sure if this is currently possible.

Comment: I like the indices approach, that way they can be copied more easily and no borrowing is necessary. I'll give it a try

Comment: This makes me think - the only reason I am putting stuff in the vec is so it can be owned by the `OptionMap` struct - it seems like there should be a vector type that can be added to but is otherwise immutable, so values that have been added to it can be borrowed while still being able to push new elements onto it.

Comment: That would result in invalid references once the vector outgrows its capacity and has to reallocate.