# Maintain a HashMap of TcpStreams in a loop

Tags: rust

I'm writing an application that uses a Distributed Hashtable (DHT) to distribute data to various nodes. When inserting data, I have to loop through it all and write various parts to different nodes. Instead of opening a new `TcpStream` object for each write, I would like to maintain a map of streams that I can use to write the data as needed. I'm very new to the Rust language and I'm having issues with lifetimes, specifically the errors

> cannot borrow 'streams' as mutable because it is already borrowed as mutable
>
> 'stream' does not live long enough.

I'm sure there is a fancy Rust way of doing this. The code I'm working with is below.

```
let mut streams = HashMap::new();
...
//get socket address to send data too
loop {
    match streams.get(&socket_addr) {
        Some(stream) => {
             capnp::serialize::write_message(*stream, &msg_builder).unwrap();
        },
        None => {
             let mut stream = TcpStream::connect(socket_addr).unwrap();
             streams.insert(socket_addr, &mut stream);
             capnp::serialize::write_message(&mut stream, &msg_builder).unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is [frowned upon to ask multiple questions in one post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829). Additionally, your questions have already been asked. The "does not live long enough" could be http://stackoverflow.com/q/31775915/155423, and "already borrowed as mutable" could be http://stackoverflow.com/q/28512394/155423. Please search for duplicates *before* asking a question, and then describe *why* your question is different from the previous questions if you decide it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot insert a reference to the stream in the `HashMap`, since the stream is a local variable that goes out of scope at the end of the `match` expression. The `HashMap` must own the stream.

The easiest way to implement this is using the [`entry()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) method on `HashMap` to open the stream at first use.

```
fn main() {
    let socket_addr = /* ... */;
    let mut streams = HashMap::new();
    let msg_builder = /* ... */;
    loop {
        let stream = streams.entry(&socket_addr).or_insert_with(|| {
            TcpStream::connect(socket_addr).unwrap()
        });
        capnp::serialize::write_message(stream, &msg_builder).unwrap();
    }
}
```