# Return all petgraph connected components in a hashtable

Tags: graph, rust, connected-components, petgraph

I'm using petgraph and I would like to extract connected components.

I want to have a `HashMap<u32, Vec<&petgraph::graph::NodeIndex>>`
with a `u32` as the identifier for the connected component and a `Vec` as a container with references to all nodes in the connected component.

If this is a bad design, don't hesitate to point out a better one; I am quite a Rust beginner.

I tried something like this:

```
extern crate fnv;
extern crate petgraph;

use petgraph::visit::Dfs;

use fnv::FnvHashMap; // a faster hash for small key
use fnv::FnvHashSet;


// structure definition
pub struct NodeAttr {
    pub name_real: String,
}

impl Default for NodeAttr {
    fn default() -> Self {
        NodeAttr {
            name_real: "default_name_for_testing".to_string(),
        }
    }
}


pub struct EdgesAttr {
    pub eval: f64,
    pub pid: f32,
    pub cov: f32, // minimum coverage
}

impl Default for EdgesAttr {
    fn default() -> Self {
        EdgesAttr {
            eval: 0.0,
            pid: 100.0,
            cov: 100.0,
        }
    }
}

pub fn cc_dfs<'a>(
    myGraph: &petgraph::Graph<NodeAttr, EdgesAttr, petgraph::Undirected>,
) -> FnvHashMap<u32, Vec<&'a petgraph::graph::NodeIndex>> {
    let mut already_visited = FnvHashSet::<&petgraph::graph::NodeIndex>::default();
    let mut map_real_index: FnvHashMap<u32, Vec<&petgraph::graph::NodeIndex>> =
        FnvHashMap::with_capacity_and_hasher(myGraph.node_count(), Default::default());

    let mut cpt = 0;

    for current_node_indice in myGraph.node_indices() {
        let mut current_vec: Vec<&petgraph::graph::NodeIndex> = Vec::new();
        if already_visited.contains(&current_node_indice) {
            continue;
        }
        let mut dfs = Dfs::new(&myGraph, current_node_indice);
        while let Some(nx) = dfs.next(&myGraph) {
            // the problem is around here
            // I believe the just assigned nx live only for the while
            //But it should live for the upper for loop. What to do?
            current_vec.push(&nx);
            already_visited.insert(&nx);
        }
        map_real_index.insert(cpt, current_vec);
        cpt = cpt + 1
    }

    return map_real_index;
}

fn main() {}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
enter[dependencies]
fnv="*"
petgraph="*"
```

With the compiler error:

```
error[E0597]: `nx` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:59:31
   |
59 |             current_vec.push(&nx);
   |                               ^^ does not live long enough
60 |             already_visited.insert(&nx);
61 |         }
   |         - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 40:1...
  --> src/main.rs:40:1
   |
40 | / pub fn cc_dfs<'a>(
41 | |     myGraph: &petgraph::Graph<NodeAttr, EdgesAttr, petgraph::Undirected>,
42 | | ) -> FnvHashMap<u32, Vec<&'a petgraph::graph::NodeIndex>> {
43 | |     let mut already_visited = FnvHashSet::<&petgraph::graph::NodeIndex>::default();
...  |
66 | |     return map_real_index;
67 | | }
   | |_^

error[E0597]: `nx` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:61:9
   |
60 |             already_visited.insert(&nx);
   |                                     -- borrow occurs here
61 |         }
   |         ^ `nx` dropped here while still borrowed
...
67 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

I cloned the node index in my vector and that worked:

```
current_vec.push(nx.clone()); // instead of (&nx)
already_visited.insert(nx.clone());`
```

I believe (maybe wrongly) that working with references will be more effective than copying.

Comment: The nature of this question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775915/binding-does-not-live-long-enough-when-storing-a-reference-to-a-vector-item-in-a, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286213/why-does-my-variable-not-live-long-enough, or any number of similar hits to the search "does not live long enough".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This much smaller piece of code exhibits the same problem ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bd55c979600379a9a7505fc8ae469a31&version=stable)):

```
let mut v = Vec::new(); // Vec<&'a NodeIndex> ... but what is 'a?
for n in 0..10 {
    let nx: NodeIndex = NodeIndex::new(n);
    v.push(&nx);
}
```

i.e., you're creating a short-lived `NodeIndex` inside a loop and trying to store a reference to it in a longer-lived `Vec`.

In this case the solution is very simple: just move the `NodeIndex` instead of taking a reference.

```
    v.push(nx)
```

In your original code the fix is no different.

```
// nit: "indices" is the plural of "index"; there is no singular word "indice"
for current_node_index in myGraph.node_indices() {
    // actually you don't need to supply a type here, but if you did...
    let mut current_vec: Vec<petgraph::graph::NodeIndex> = Vec::new();
    if already_visited.contains(&current_node_index) {
        continue;
    }
    let mut dfs = Dfs::new(&myGraph, current_node_index);
    while let Some(nx) = dfs.next(&myGraph) {
        current_vec.push(nx);
        //               ^-----v- Look Ma, no &s!
        already_visited.insert(nx);
    }
    map_real_index.insert(cpt, current_vec);
    cpt = cpt + 1
}
```

"But," you say, "I don't want to copy an entire `NodeIndex`! I just want to have a pointer to it! `NodeIndex` is a big fat hairy struct, right?"

Well, if that (an owning pointer) is really what you need, `Box` is what you almost always want. But first look at the definition of [`NodeIndex`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.10/petgraph/graph/struct.NodeIndex.html) and check out the [source code](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.10/src/petgraph/graph_impl/mod.rs.html#89), if you want to know how heavyweight these indices really are:

```
pub struct NodeIndex<Ix=DefaultIx>(Ix);
```

A `NodeIndex` is just an `Ix`, which is (if you look up [`DefaultIx`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.10/petgraph/graph/type.DefaultIx.html)) just an alias for `u32`. On a 64 bit PC, that's actually *smaller* than the pointer you were trying to store, and in Rust, you don't pay any extra cost for using it -- at runtime, it's really *just* a `u32`.

Conveniently, [`NodeIndex` is `Copy`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.10/petgraph/graph/struct.NodeIndex.html#impl-Copy) (when `Ix` is `Copy`), so you don't even need to throw that extra `.clone()` in; you can just do `current_vec.push(nx)` followed by `already_visited.insert(nx)` as I did above. (But even if you do write `.clone()`, you pay no runtime cost for doing so; it's just unnecessary.)